# Dynamically sized array elements in Ada

Tags: c, arrays, ada, ffi

So I have the following Ada array declaration buried inside a package body, that eventually gets passed to a C function

```
declare
    type t_buffer is array (0 .. ARR_SIZE) of Unsigned_32;
    buffer : constant access t_buffer := new t_buffer;
begin

   c_obj.buffer_p := buffer (1)'Address;
   c_obj.buffer_length := Unsigned_64 (buffer'Last);
   for idx in Integer range buffer'Range loop
      buffer (idx) := Unsigned_32 (idx * 4);
   end loop;
end
```

However, the elements of the array aren't actually always `Unsigned_32`/`uint32_t` - it varies between `uint8_t`, `uint16_t`, `uint32_t` & `uint64_t`, depending on a (runtime) parameter. This means that when it gets read as a (for example) uint16_t array in the C code, the numbers are coming out as a sequence of 0,0,4,0,8,0,... instead of the intended 0,4,8,... when the `uint32_t` is "split" into 2 different numbers.

Ada doesn't have something approximating dependent types so I can't dynamically create the array type. I'm not sure how I can solve this at all nicely, possibly something to do with making an array of Unsigned_8 and bitshifting as appropriate?

Comment: Not really related to your question, but Buffer has Arr_Size + 1 components; that is, Buffer'Length = Arr_Size + 1. Buffer'Last = Arr_Size. Most C operations want Buffer_Length to be Buffer'Length, and iterate from zero to Buffer_Length - 1.

Answer (score 3):

The way Ada works, you have to have four different array types.

But you can encapsulate the selection of the array types in a variant record:

```ada
package Variant_Records is

   type Word_Sizes is range 8 .. 64
     with Static_Predicate => Word_Sizes in 8 | 16 | 32 | 64;

   type Data_8_Bit  is mod 2 **  8 with Size =>  8;
   type Data_16_Bit is mod 2 ** 16 with Size => 16;
   type Data_32_Bit is mod 2 ** 32 with Size => 32;
   type Data_64_Bit is mod 2 ** 64 with Size => 64;

   type Array_8_Bit  is array (Positive range <>) of Data_8_Bit;
   type Array_16_Bit is array (Positive range <>) of Data_16_Bit;
   type Array_32_Bit is array (Positive range <>) of Data_32_Bit;
   type Array_64_Bit is array (Positive range <>) of Data_64_Bit;

   type Data_Array (Word_Size : Word_Sizes;
                    Length    : Natural) is
      record
         case Word_Size is
            when  8 => Data_8  : Array_8_Bit  (1 .. Length);
            when 16 => Data_16 : Array_16_Bit (1 .. Length);
            when 32 => Data_32 : Array_32_Bit (1 .. Length);
            when 64 => Data_64 : Array_64_Bit (1 .. Length);
         end case;
      end record;

end Variant_Records;
```

And then an example of some usage:

```ada
with Variant_Records;

procedure Using_Variant_Records is
   use Variant_Records;

   A : Data_Array (Word_Size =>  8, Length => 16);
   B : Data_Array (Word_Size => 64, Length =>  2);
begin
   for I in A.Data_8'Range loop
      A.Data_8 (I) := 2 * Data_8_Bit (I) + 4;
   end loop;

   for I in B.Data_64'Range loop
      B.Data_64 (I) := Data_64_Bit (8 ** I) + 4;
   end loop;

   declare
      D : Data_Array := B;
   begin
      for E of D.Data_64 loop
         E := E * 8;
      end loop;
   end;
end Using_Variant_Records;
```

Comment: That sounds useful. I'm fairly new to Ada though, can you give an example/links?

Comment: @LordAro I hope the added example explains my suggestion.

Comment: Nearly there! Not sure how to actually make use of this though - I've currently got `buffer : constant access t_buffer := new t_buffer;` for the fixed size version in the package body declaration, how can i initialise this version in the correct place in the main package body?